# GitHub initialization trouble

Tags: git, github

When trying to add a new GitHub repository to my project, I am getting

> fatal: remote origin already exists.

Then, when I try to do

```
git push -u origin master
```

I get another error and it gives an error of faulty path. This path continues to show up even after I typed it in correctly like it keeps reverting back to my original mistake. See screen shot below.

```
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/richardewing/myapp/.git/

$ git commit -m "first commit"
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git remote add origin https://github.com/ricke2005/Learn-rails-2.git
***fatal: remote origin already exists***.

$ git push -u origin master
fatal: unable to access 'https://github,com/ricke2005/Learn-rails-2.git/': Could not resolve host: github,com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not reinitialize your git again for a separate project, go to your git directory, and clone the new project using 
`git clone https://github.com/ricke2005/Learn-rails-2.git`

then move to this new project directory `Learn-rails-2` in your git folder, and you can start working on that project.

Answer (score 2):

As @bureaquete suggests, you have set up an incorrect origin. `git remote -v` will show the existing remote named *origin*, and it will show `github,com`, with a comma.  Use `git remote remove origin` to delete that definition, then of course `git remote add origin https://github.com/ricke2005/Learn-rails-2.git` to re-create it correctly.

At that point, I would simply `git pull origin master` to synchronize the local repository with the remote, and then proceed normally.  No need to re-initialize your local unless that's what you really want.